# Including check in Approval Process

Tags: approval-process

There is an approval process on which I have to make one change. I have to ensure that the approver can only approve if the value of status field was set to 'complete' by the submitter. So if the approver tries to approve without the status field being set to complete an error message should be shown. I know keeping the check with the submitter would make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can reach this effect by including an approval step that rejects the record if the status field isn't set to 'complete':

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Fred 's answer (which occurs after any notification emails/chatter feed approval requests - that may be deemed spurious by the recipient), you can 'encourage' the user to not submit the object for approval by adding the following custom formula field to your Detail layout as the top most field in a 1-column, untitled section.

```
Field name = `Alerts__c`  Field Type = Text
Field value = {!IF(ISPICKVAL(Foo__c.status__c,'Complete',
                   NULL,
                   IMAGE('/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif','Yellow',12,12) &
                         'Records without Status = Completed cannot be submitted for approval'
                   )}
```

You can use a bigger image than 12x12 if you want to really get the user's attention.

Removing the Submit for Approval button altogether from the detail page requires separate record types with corresponding page layouts managed behind the scenes via workflow/process builder that use the value of `Status__c` to decide. This might not be practical if you are already using recordTypes for business use cases.